# Bitwise right shift >> in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, bit-manipulation, shift

I have a variable (unsigned int) `part_1`.

If I do this:
`NSLog(@"%u %08x", part_1, part_1);` (print unsigned value, and hex value) it outputs:

`2063597568 7b000000`

(only first two will have values).

I want to convert this to

`0000007b`

So i've tried doing
`unsigned int part_1b =  part_1 >> 6` (and lots of variations)

But this outputs:

`32243712 01ec0000`

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to shift by 6*4 = 24 bits, not just 6 bits. Each '0' in the hex printf represents 4 bits.

```
unsigned int part_1b = part_1 >> 24;
                                 ^^
```