# iOS macro for setting color

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning iOS development and I found a macro to set a color, but I do not understand how it works.

The macro:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

I understand bit and and or and stuff but I do not see how this translates to a valid color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIColorFromRGB(0xrrggbb)
```

Where `rr`, `gg` and `bb` represent the red, green and blue values in hexadecimal.

Example:

```
UIColorFromRGB(0xff0000)
```

The above code would return an red `UIColor`.

Full explanation:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

1. `#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue)`

   Defines a utility macro for creating a `UIColor` from an HTML-style hexadecimal RGB color. Example: `0xaf45ff`
2. `(rgbValue & 0xFF0000)`

   This bitmask extracts the red value from `rgbValue`. In our example, this would result in `0xaf0000`.
3. `rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16`

   This is used to shift the bits of `0xaf00000` by 16 places to get us `0x0000af` so that…
4. `((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0`

   …it can be divided by `255.0` to get us the percentage of red in the color, as `UIColor` represents colors as percentages (`0.34f`, `0.28f`, `0.88f`, etc).

Comment: But why the bit shift >> 16 etc?

Comment: `(rgbValue & 0xFF00000)` would give `0xFF00000` for a red color. We need to change it to a `0x0000FF` or `255.0` to be acceptable to the `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]` method.

Comment: @MouNtant You're welcome. I updated my answer with a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

The `rgbValue` need not be hexadeximal. You can use it like

`UIColorFromRGB(150)` in turn it will perform

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((150 & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((150 & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(150 & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

For a better understanding of bitwise check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19794568/1307844)

Answer (score 0):

You would use it like any normal RGB value.

RGB values are formatted like this, `RRGGBB`

but this argument (rgbValue) requires the 0x in front of it making it hexadecimal,

Thus you would use your macro as such:

`UIColorFromRGB(0xRRGGBB);` or `UIColorFromRGB(0x653593);`

---

`#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0];`

If your question is about understanding how the `((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0` works lets take it bit by bit.

First we notice that in the end we'll be dividing the upper half (numerator) by 255.0. This is standard practice with `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` so we'll need the numerator to be a float. So we cast the value as a `float`.

Lets evaluate the `(rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8` next. Obviously the `rgbValue` is the the value we passed to the function. As we discovered earlier, the value of `rgbValue` is actually hexadecimal. The first part, (rgbValue & 0xFF00) means bitwise `AND`. Then the `>>` bitwise shift the bits right 8 spaces. This in return, returns only (in this case) the green value from the rgbValue variable. After that we divide by 255.0 and get the actual accepted value that `[UIColor colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha]` accepts.